# Express the derivative of$ (f(5x^5+11))^2$ in terms of the differentiable function f and its derivative g

Tags: calculus

Express the derivative of $(f(5x^5+11))^2$ in terms of the differentiable function $f$ and its derivative $g$

Tried to derivate $(f(5x^5+11))^2$, and came up with $50 x^4 f(5 x^5+11) f'(5 x^5+11)$. I think im walkin in the wild here..

Answer (score 2):

You did fine-three stages of chain rule.  Now the problem statement says that $f'(x)=g(x)$ so you should substitute that in and you are done.

Comment: Then, the answer becomes 50x^4f(5x^5+11)g(5x^5+11)? tried this the first time, and went out it was wrong...

Comment: That is what I get, too.